# It’s nothing our butterfly curtains couldn’t fix

Tags: meaning

In Inside Out Animation joy says:
Hey, it’s nothing our butterfly curtains couldn’t fix. I read somewhere that an empty room is an opportunity.

What does she mean when she say:

> it’s nothing our butterfly curtains couldn’t fix.

Comment: It means their butterfly curtains could certainly fix it.

Comment: I suspect the question involves the meaning of "butterfly curtains."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, "it's nothing *x* couldn't fix" is just another way of saying "*x* can fix it."

I'm not familiar with the film, but from [here](https://medium.com/cinenation-show/the-power-of-nostalgia-in-inside-out-ff8c6d2de5b1) I gather that the problem that needs to be fixed is a depressing empty room. Another brief search leads me to believe that "butterfly curtains" are simply curtains with pictures of butterflies on them, rather than an actual type of curtain such as panel curtains or sash curtains. So the character Joy is saying that hanging curtains with pictures of butterflies on them will "brighten up" a dreary empty room and make it less depressing and more attractive and enjoyable.